# use start out of QProcess?

Tags: windows, qt, winapi

when I type

```
start ms-settings
```

in command prompt from Windows, it starts the settings application properly. When I try the same via QProcess.execute(), it returns a -2. The problem seems to be the "start" part of the call, it seems to be something command-shell specific.

So is there a possibility to start such a program out of Qt using QProcess?

Thanks!

Comment: In this particular case, you can use the URI scheme (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/launch-settings-app) and open it via a URL, e.g. `QDesktopServices::openUrl(QUrl("ms-settings:network-wifi"));`

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld this works great! Is there also a possibility to wait until the user has closed the settings again? Like waiting for a normal process to end?

Comment: I don’t think so, at least not with Qt API. I would also expect that the OS doesn’t give you enough information, the same way as it doesn’t tell you what happens with a browser tab or email client after you clicked a URL somewhere… I think with something like settings it would also be of limited usability (what if the user just puts the settings to the background?) Does “start ms-settings” have an option to block until the settings are closed?

Comment: or use `ShellExecute(NULL, TEXT("open"), ("ms-settings:"), NULL, NULL, SW_NORMAL);` or `ShellExecuteEx`